# Getting updating in codebehind C# variable to asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I wrote a small code in c# that reads files from the hard drive and outputs that info to a webpage using asp.net.

Information about those files is being changed in the codebehind.

I managed to create variables to read and display the info on the webpage, but they change only after a refresh. When I used setTimeout it would always read the same variable, leaving me thinking that the codebehind does not get re-executed.

How would it be possible to have them updated live without needing to refresh the entire page?

Comment: There's two main techniques for updating a webpage without updating the entire page. They're called AJAX and Web Sockets. I suggest you do some research about those.

Comment: This is too broad. There's many possibilities, look up ajax, wepapi, websockets for instance and determine what suits you best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat vague but if you want updates to the values on your page after loading, you'll need to use some javascript to grab new values and then more javascript to update values on your page.

There are some great frameworks out there. Unless you have a lot of front-end logic you need to perform through javascript, I'd keep it as simple as possible and throw jQuery in there for the AJAX calls (fyi, this is not the only solution, there are 10+ different ways to skin this same cat).

If you want a bit more efficiency, you could look into using SignalR - which wraps long polling or web sockets (depending on browser capability) on the front end and signals those subscribing pages on the backend only when changes have occurred to data.

Link: http://www.asp.net/signalr

There is no "right" answer to your question so the best I or anybody can do is guide you in a direction. Hopefully this answer helps you.